# Subset and complements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $B \subset A$, show that $B = A-(A-B)$.

How can I prove this? Does not make sense to me because if we have $A-(A-B)$ then that means $B$ does not contain in the subset of $A-(A-B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A-(A-B)=A\cap(A\cap B^C)^C = A\cap(A^C \cup B) =(A\cap A^C )\cup (A\cap B)=A\cap B$$
Since $B\subset A$, $A\cap B=B$.

Comment: Thanks. Is $A-(A-B)=A\cap(A\cap B^C)^C$ an identity?

Comment: @Q.matin Yes. Because $A-B=A\cap B^C$.

Comment: @Q.matin It may help to think of $(A-B)$ as $\{x| x \in A \text{ and } x \not\in B\}$ which is $(A \cap B^c)$.

Comment: $A-B=\{x:x\in A \text{ and } x\notin B\}=\{x:x\in A\}\cap \{x:x\notin B\} = A\cap B^C$

Comment: @emka yes it does. Thank you!

Comment: Tetori thanks a lot!

Comment: @tetori I want to prove this question another way. Can you tell me the way I did it is correct? Let $x\in B$ then x will not be in $A-B$ but $x\in A -(A-B)$ thus if $x\in B$ then $x\in B\subset A$. Is that correct too?

Comment: @Q.matin I think it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} A-(A-B) &= \{ x \mid x \in A \wedge x \notin \{x \mid x \in A \wedge x \notin B\}\} \\ &= \{ x \mid x \in A \wedge x \in \neg \{ x \mid x \in A \wedge x \notin B\}\} \\ &= \{ x \mid x \in A \wedge x \in \{ x \mid x \notin A \vee x \in B\}\}\\ &= \{ x \mid x \in A \wedge \left( x \notin A \vee x \in B \right)\} \\ &= \{ x \mid (x \in A \wedge x \notin A) \vee (x \in A \wedge x \in B)\} \\ &= \{ x \mid x \in A \wedge x \in B\}\\ &=A \cap B\end{align}$$
Since $B \subseteq A$,

$$A-(A-B)=A \cap B =B$$

Answer (score 0):

A standard method for proving set equality is to show two inclusion statements must hold.  That will work here.